# Pipes in Angular

Tags: angular

I am using pipe in angular4. Its working fine on local server. But when i am using the command ng build --prod , then its showing error.
Error: Property searchText does not exists on type 'HomeComponent'.
Here is my code.

home.component.html

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="search text goes here">
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let c of characters | filter : searchText">
{{c}}
</li>
</ul>
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FilterPipe} from '../filter.pipe';

@Component({
selector: 'app-about',
templateUrl: './about.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
 characters = [
"london",
"USA",
"Paris"
 ]
constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
  }

 }
```

filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
name: 'filter'
 })
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
if(!items) return [];
if(!searchText) return items;
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
return items.filter( it => {
  return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
  });
  }
 }
```

app.module.ts

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
 import {RouterModule,Routes} from '@angular/router';
 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
 import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';


@NgModule({
 declarations: [
 AppComponent,
 HomeComponent,
 FilterPipe
],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path:'home',component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'',redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full'},
   ])
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })

 export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: you have to initialize `searchText` in your `home.component.ts` like this `searchText: string='';` or `searchText: string;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no variable name 
searchText in your ts file of home.component.ts

so in your ts file add

```
searchText: string;
```